# Get Event Logs by Address filtered by Topics——Etherscan API

Tags: python-3.x

https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/logs#get-event-logs-by-address-filtered-by-topics

If I want to get all USDT ERC20 contract's approval transacations, how can I fill topic0?
If I still want to get all transacations about fix spender address, how can I fill topic1?

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=0&toBlock=latest&address=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&topic0=??&topic0_1_opr=and&topic1=??&page=1&offset=1000&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

I tried for a long time, has been responding to the error, thank you for answering, I am new

Answer (score 0):

this code works:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api'
params = {
    "module": "logs",
    "action": "getLogs",
    "fromBlock": 15073139,
    "toBlock": 15074139,
    "address": "0x59728544b08ab483533076417fbbb2fd0b17ce3a",
    "topic0": "0x27c4f0403323142b599832f26acd21c74a9e5b809f2215726e244a4ac588cd7d",
    "topic0_1_opr": "and",
    "topic1": "0x00000000000000000000000023581767a106ae21c074b2276d25e5c3e136a68b",
    "page": 1,
    "offset": 1000,
    "apikey": "YourApiKeyToken"
}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(r.text)
```

You can modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, what I need is all the Owner addresses in the ERC20 USDT approval event that match the specific Spender address, topic0 is 0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925, topic1 is the Owner address and topic2 is the Spender address, so the answer is below

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=logs
   &action=getLogs
   &fromBlock=0
   &toBlock=latest
   &address=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7
   &topic0=0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925
   &topic0_2_opr=and
   &topic2=0x00000000000000000000000000000Spender address
   &page=1
   &offset=1000
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```